# Random forest problems w/ 20 newsgroups

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm trying to run a Random forest algorithm using 20 newsgroups dataset but I don't know how to solve the problem. I used a SVM and NB before with the same dataset and it works well.

```
 from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


dataset_train=fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',shuffle=True)
dataset_test=fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test',shuffle=True)
vectorizer=CountVectorizer()

x_train_counts=vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset_train.data)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',lowercase=True,ngram_range=(1,5))
x_train_tfidf=vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset_train.data)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
model=model.fit(dataset_train.data,dataset_train.target)
```

and that's the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/new_randomforest.py", line 18, in <module>
    model=model.fit(dataset_train.data,dataset_train.target)
  File "C:\Users\forest.py", line 247, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
  File "C:\Users\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "From: lerxst@wam.umd.edu (where's my thing)\nSubject: WHAT car is this!?\nNntp-Posting-Host: rac3.wam.umd.edu\nOrganization: University of Maryland, College Park\nLines: 15\n\n I was wondering if anyone out there could enlighten me on this car I saw\nthe other day. It was a 2-door sports car, looked to be from the late 60s/\nearly 70s. It was called a Bricklin. The doors were really small. In addition,\nthe front bumper was separate from the rest of the body. This is \nall I know. If anyone can tellme a model name, engine specs, years\nof production, where this car is made, history, or whatever info you\nhave on this funky looking car, please e-mail.\n\nThanks,\n- IL\n   ---- brought to you by your neighborhood Lerxst ----\n\n\n\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use train vector that you created (here `x_train_tfidf`) while fitting the model

```
model.fit(x_train_tfidf,dataset_train.target)
```

`dataset_train.data` is a list of string here. That's why the error.

**PS::** Basically what the error say is that, you are trying to fit `string` in your model which is not allowed. Quoting from [`documentation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit)

```
fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)
```

> X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]
>
> The training input samples. Internally, its dtype will be converted to **dtype=np.float32**. If a sparse matrix is provided, it will be converted into a sparse csc_matrix.